# ExcelDataReader close exception "The directory is not empty."

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I am getting `The directory is not empty` exception from my code only when I deploy it on the server.

Debugging through the exception found that there is some glitch with the `excelReader.Close();`

Code is as follow

```
 IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;    
 DeleteFile(path);
 postedFile.SaveAs(path);

 FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
 if (Extension.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
 {
      excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
 }
 else if (Extension.ToLower() == ".xls")
 {
      excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
 }
 excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

 DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

 if (result.Tables.Count > 0)
 {
      dt = result.Tables[0];
 }
 stream.Close();
 stream.Dispose();
 DeleteFile(path);
 if (excelReader != null)
 {
      File.AppendAllText(
         @"D:\Websites\registry.aan.com\OldAuditLogs\Error.txt",
        "excelReader if");

      excelReader.Close();
      excelReader.Dispose();
 }
 else {
     File.AppendAllText(
        @"D:\Websites\registry.aan.com\OldAuditLogs\Error.txt",
        "excelReader else");
 }

 File.AppendAllText(
   @"D:\Websites\registry.aan.com\OldAuditLogs\Error.txt",
   "excelReader out");

 result.Dispose();
```

Comment: if you change `excelReader.Close()` to `if (excelReader != null) { excelReader.Close() }`  does the error go away?

Comment: why are you deleting the folder? shouldn't you delete just the file?

Comment: Hello iliketocode, thanks for your quick response, I have modified the code as you suggested but i still get the same exception. the code runs with no flaws on my local machine, but when i deploy the same on the server it get the exception. I have modified the code as above.

Comment: Hello muratgu, thanks for your quick response, i have removed the section  for folder deletion.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Upgrading the package from 2.1.1 to 3.4.2 fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade ExcelDataReader to version 3.4.2